# Programs that appear to install perfectly during a Docker build are not present in run containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apt-get

I have a dockerfile that appears to successfully install various programs.

Here, for example, I install sfdx-cli:

```
RUN wget -O - https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz  | tar Jxv &&     sfdx/install &&     rm -rf sfdx
```

I know it's successful because a subsequent line causes it to update itself.

Here's another example, where I install apt-transport-https:

```
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

I know this works because the next line installs heroku, which relies on apt-transport-https:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y heroku
```

When I run a container based on this image, though, neither sfdx-cli nor apt-transport-https are present. I've searched using "find /" commands and can't find them anywhere, let alone in their expected locations.

the container in general runs fine, with many programs present and working. The "heroku" command, for examples, works fine.

I'm obviously missing something basic about the way docker works, but I can't find anything online about this.

Here's the current Dockerfile: https://gist.github.com/alexed1/ad4917f53bed34318e1aa2801a82e911

Here's my build command:

```
docker build . -t alexed1:dev5
```

Here's my run command:

```
docker run -it -v /Users/aedelstein/Dropbox/dev:/home/alexed/dev \
   -p 8000:8000 -p 5000:5000 -p 80:80 -p 1717:1717 alexed1/dev5
```

Comment: Could you share the respective Dockerfile? Is it possible that the installed packages are removed again in a later build step or anything similar?

Comment: Please share your full Dockerfile, what commands you are using to build, and what commands you are using to run - you're failing somewhere in one of those 3.

Comment: edited to provide that data.

Comment: `alexed1:dev5` != `alexed1/dev5`

Comment: That's quite a long Dockerfile without any layer consolidation. What storage (graph) driver are you using? `docker info  -f '{{ .Driver }}'`

Comment: @AlexEdelstein - Yeah, your issue here is definitely that you're not using the image you built. You built the image `alexed1:dev5` and you're running the image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/alexed1/dev5/

Comment: @BMitch : overlay2 Thanks all for the very fast assists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image names are made up of two components and `repository` and a `:tag`. If no `:tag` is specified it defaults to `:latest`

The container being run is using the image `alexed1/dev5`. This equates to the tag `alexed1/dev5:latest`

The image being built is different, and is being tagged `alexed1:dev5`

To run the built image, use

```
docker run -it -v /Users/aedelstein/Dropbox/dev:/home/alexed/dev \
  -p 8000:8000 -p 5000:5000 -p 80:80 -p 1717:1717 alexed1:dev5
```